# How to consume a BlockingCollection<T> in batches

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, producer-consumer, blockingcollection

I've come up with some code to consume all wating items from a queue. Rather than processing the items 1 by 1, it makes sense to process all waiting items as a set.

I've declared my queue like this.

```
private BlockingCollection<Item> items = 
    new BlockingCollection<Item>(new ConcurrentQueue<Item>);
```

Then, on a consumer thread, I plan to read the items in batches like this,

```
Item nextItem;
while (this.items.TryTake(out nextItem, -1))
{
    var workToDo = new List<Item>();
    workToDo.Add(nextItem);

    while(this.items.TryTake(out nextItem))
    {
        workToDo.Add(nextItem);
    }

    // process workToDo, then go back to the queue.
}
```

This approach lacks the utility of [`GetConsumingEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx) and I can't help wondering if I've missed a better way, or if my approach is flawed.

Is there a better way to consume a `BlockingCollection<T>` in batches?

Comment: You could do a Take(50) on the ConsumingEnumerable but you would lose the effect of the 50ms timeout. So choose what is more important.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, you're right, I don't actually need that, it would be problematic it items were produced at a faster rate.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, question edited accordingly.

Comment: No a faster rate would be no problem, a slower one would, Your current code (w/o timeout) is less suitable to be replaced by ConsumingEnumerable

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I guess it depends if I want to wait for bigger batches, in which case something different is called for.

Comment: That's what I meant with making a choice: min/max batch size and min/max waiting time.

Answer (score 6):

A solution is to use the [`BufferBlock<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.bufferblock-1) from 
[System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/4.11.0-preview3.19551.4) (which is included in .net core 3+). It does not use [`GetConsumingEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx), but it still does allow you the same utility, mainly:

- allows parallel processing w/ multiple (symmetrical and/or asymmetrical) consumers and producers
- thread safe (allowing for the above) - no race conditions to worry about
- can be cancelled by a cancellation token and/or collection completion
- consumers block until data is available, avoiding wasting CPU cycles on polling

There is also a [`BatchBlock<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.batchblock-1), but that limits you to fixed sized batches.

```cs
var buffer = new BufferBlock<Item>();
while (await buffer.OutputAvailableAsync())
{
    if (buffer.TryReceiveAll(out var items))
        //process items
}
```

Here is a working example, which demos the following:

- multiple symmetrical consumers which process variable length batches in parallel
- multiple symmetrical producers (not truly operating in parallel in this example)
- ability to complete the collection when the producers are done
- to keep the example short, I did not demonstrate the use of a `CancellationToken`
- ability to wait until the producers and/or consumers are done
- ability to call from an area that doesn't allow async, such as a constructor
- the `Thread.Sleep()` calls are not required, but help simulate some processing time that would occur in more taxing scenarios
- both the `Task.WaitAll()` and the `Thread.Sleep()` can optionally be converted to their async equivalents
- no need to use any external libraries

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var buffer = new BufferBlock<string>();

        // Kick off consumer task(s)
        List<Task> consumers = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            consumers.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                // need to copy this due to lambda variable capture
                var num = i; 
                while (await buffer.OutputAvailableAsync())
                {
                    if (buffer.TryReceiveAll(out var items))
                        Console.WriteLine($"Consumer {num}:    " + 
                            items.Aggregate((a, b) => a + ", " + b));

                        // real life processing would take some time
                        await Task.Delay(500); 
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"Consumer {num} complete");
            }));

            // give consumer tasks time to activate for a better demo
            Thread.Sleep(100); 
        }

        // Kick off producer task(s)
        List<Task> producers = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            producers.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                for (int j = 0 + (1000 * i); j < 500 + (1000 * i); j++)
                    buffer.Post(j.ToString());
            }));

            // space out the producers for a better demo
            Thread.Sleep(10); 
        }

        // may also use the async equivalent
        Task.WaitAll(producers.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine("Finished waiting on producers");

        // demo being able to complete the collection
        buffer.Complete(); 

        // may also use the async equivalent
        Task.WaitAll(consumers.ToArray()); 
        Console.WriteLine("Finished waiting on consumers");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Here is a mondernised and simplified version of the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

class Program
{
    private static async Task Main()
    {
        var buffer = new BufferBlock<string>();

        // Kick off consumer task(s)
        var consumers = new List<Task>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var id = i;
            consumers.Add(Task.Run(() => StartConsumer(id, buffer)));

            // give consumer tasks time to activate for a better demo
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }

        // Kick off producer task(s)
        var producers = new List<Task>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var pid = i;
            producers.Add(Task.Run(() => StartProducer(pid, buffer)));

            // space out the producers for a better demo
            await Task.Delay(10);
        }

        // may also use the async equivalent
        await Task.WhenAll(producers);
        Console.WriteLine("Finished waiting on producers");

        // demo being able to complete the collection
        buffer.Complete();

        // may also use the async equivalent
        await Task.WhenAll(consumers);
        Console.WriteLine("Finished waiting on consumers");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static async Task StartConsumer(
            int id,
            IReceivableSourceBlock<string> buffer)
    {
        while (await buffer.OutputAvailableAsync())
        {
            if (buffer.TryReceiveAll(out var items))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Consumer {id}: " + 
                    items.Aggregate((a, b) => a + ", " + b));
            }

            // real life processing would take some time
            await Task.Delay(500);
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Consumer {id} complete");
    }

    private static Task StartProducer(int pid, ITargetBlock<string> buffer)
    {
        for (var j = 0 + (1000 * pid); j < 500 + (1000 * pid); j++)
        {
            buffer.Post(j.ToString());
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: The styling and quality of the example could be improved e.g. make it fit on the screen and use `await Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep`, and other improvements too I suspect.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have reformatted to eliminate horizontal scrolling. I debated using `await Task.Delay()` instead of `Thread.Sleep()`, but I wanted to show that this code can be created from a constructor or other places where async isn't allowed. What do you think?

Comment: I think you should have and [async Main](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/30/c-7-series-part-2-async-main/) and that you should not sleep or delay in a constructor.

Comment: I couldn't resist tweaking your code, see the edited answer.

Comment: The Sleep()/Delay() is to simulate more intensive processing in real life. Thus, I wanted to include it in the example (although it should be be replaced by real code in production). At the same time, I did not want to confuse anyone into thinking that async was required to run this code. Thanks for posting the async version of the code though!

Answer (score 2):

While not as good as `ConcurrentQueue<T>` in some ways, my own `LLQueue<T>` allows for a batched dequeue with a [AtomicDequeueAll](http://hackcraft.github.com/Ariadne/documentation/html/M_Ariadne_Collections_LLQueue_1_AtomicDequeueAll.htm) method where all items currently on the queue are taken from it in a single (atomic and thread-safe) operation, and are then in a non-threadsafe collection for consumption by a single thread. This method was designed precisely for the scenario where you want to batch the read operations.

This isn't blocking though, though it could be used to create a blocking collection easily enough:

```
public BlockingBatchedQueue<T>
{
  private readonly AutoResetEvent _are = new AutoResetEvent(false);
  private readonly LLQueue<T> _store;
  public void Add(T item)
  {
    _store.Enqueue(item);
    _are.Set();
  }
  public IEnumerable<T> Take()
  {
    _are.WaitOne();
    return _store.AtomicDequeueAll();
  }
  public bool TryTake(out IEnumerable<T> items, int millisecTimeout)
  {
    if(_are.WaitOne(millisecTimeout))
    {
      items = _store.AtomicDequeueAll();
      return true;
    }
    items = null;
    return false;
  }
}
```

That's a starting point that doesn't do the following:

1. Deal with a pending waiting reader upon disposal.
2. Worry about a potential race with multiple readers both being triggered by a write happening while one was reading (it just considers the occasional empty result enumerable to be okay).
3. Place any upper-bound on writing.

All of which could be added too, but I wanted to keep to the minimum of some practical use, that hopefully isn't buggy within the defined limitations above.

Comment: I wonder, if you made a `BatchedQueue<T>` that implemented `IProducerConsumer<IEnumerable<T>>` ... or if `LLQueue<T>` did, now I'm wondering if its me who is missing somthing or rather, its the framework.

Comment: `LLQueue<T>` implements `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>` alright, but using that directly in a blocking collection means we lose the access to the `AtomicDequeueAll()` that is the only advantage it has here over anything else. You could try wrapping `LLQueue<T>` in a class that implemented `IProducerConsumer<IEnumerable<T>>` by calling `EnqueueRange()` and `AtomicDequeueAll()`, but `EnqueueRange()` isn't atomic, so there could be periods when you're waiting to read while there are actually items there to be read, because the blocking collection doesn't realise it.

Comment: The `TryAdd` would need to be atomic for the whole `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Exactly. `EnqueueRange()` is little more than a convenience on repeatedly calling `Enqueue()`. Fine if you don't mind it being inter-leaved with other `Enqueue()s`, but useless if we were to wrap it in something used by something that expects it to be atomic. That said, I imagine `BlockingCollection` doesn't allow reads until a write has returned, so it might actually be okay in that regard. I really don't like the idea of stretching expected behaviour that much though.

Comment: Actually, just taking a look at it for another reason, it appears I forgot my own code: EnqueueRange() is currently atomic, I had just decided not to guarantee that because I wasn't sure if it was the best approach so I wanted the right to change that later. With the current code, you could definitely make a `BlockingCollection<IEnumerable<T>>` that is atomic for both adding and removing.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no better way. Your approach is basically correct.

You could wrap the "consume-in-batches" functionality in an extension method, for ease of use. The implementation below uses the same `List<T>` as a buffer during the whole enumeration, with the intention to prevent the allocation of a new buffer on each iteration. It also includes an optional `maxSize` parameter, that allows to limit the size of the emitted batches:

```
/// <summary>
/// Consumes the items in the collection in batches. Each batch contains all
/// the items that are immediately available, up to a specified maximum number.
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<T[]> GetConsumingEnumerableBatch<T>(
    this BlockingCollection<T> source, int maxSize = -1,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    if (maxSize == -1) maxSize = Array.MaxLength;
    if (maxSize < 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(maxSize));
    if (source.IsCompleted) yield break;
    List<T> buffer = new();
    while (source.TryTake(out T item, Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken))
    {
        Debug.Assert(buffer.Count == 0);
        buffer.Add(item);
        while (buffer.Count < maxSize && source.TryTake(out item))
            buffer.Add(item);
        T[] batch = buffer.ToArray();
        int batchSize = batch.Length;
        buffer.Clear();
        yield return batch;
        if (batchSize < buffer.Capacity / 4)
            buffer.Capacity = buffer.Capacity / 2; // Shrink oversized buffer
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
foreach (Item[] batch in this.items.GetConsumingEnumerableBatch())
{
    // Process the batch
}
```

The buffer is shrank in half, every time an emitted batch is smaller than a quarter of the buffer's capacity. This will keep the buffer in control, in case it has become oversized at some point during the enumeration.

The intention of the `if (source.IsCompleted) yield break` line is to [replicate the behavior](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/69320#issuecomment-1133587458) of the built-in [`GetConsumingEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.getconsumingenumerable) method, when it is supplied with an already canceled token, and the collection is empty and completed.

In case of cancellation, no buffered messages are in danger of being lost. The `cancellationToken` is checked only when the `buffer` is empty.

A simpler implementation without memory management features can be found in the [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71786021/1) of this answer.